# Passing multiple arguments in os.system

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I am developing a gui and on the press of a button it should launch a software 'ansa' and load a script which will merge 3 files together.

this input argument is a file path, so that the script can load this file.

This is the command I am currently using in python:

```
os.system("start ansa -exec load_script: 'ansa123.py' -exec \"foo('" + self.path[0] + "')\"")
```

`self.path[0]` is the file path stored as a local variable in the gui python code and `ansa123.py` is the script to be loaded into ansa

This is how the script ansa123.py loads the input argument: (the function foo is passed to the script as input)

```
def foo(fileName):
```

This works well for one argument, but I want to send 3 arguments which correspond to 3 file paths stored as strings.

When I send 3 arguments I get an error:

> TypeError: system() takes at most 1 argument (3 given)

Comment: How are you "sending 3 arguments"? Please show the full code you're using for the command. Also consider using QProcess instead.

Comment: I have tried to separate them using commas. 
**os.system("start ansa -exec load_script: 'Merge_Script.py' -exec \"foo('" + (self.mergefile0, self.mergefile1, self.mergefile2) + "') \"")** 

I know this isnt correct and I dont know the right way to do it. Could you maybe tell me how to use the QProcess for the same? I am not very experienced in programming. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to change `foo()` so it can take more than one filename argument.

```
def foo(*filenames):
```

The code of `foo()` should then loop over all the filenames.

Then change your `os.system()` call so it puts quotes around each filename, not the whole argument list.

```
filenames = ",".join([f"'{filename}'" for filename in self.path])
os.system(f"start ansa -exec load_script: 'ansa123.py' -exec \"foo(${filenames})\"")
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for this. It does work and, I tried it by passing a lambda function as well and, it works. Here is the syntax for the same:

**os.system("start ansa -exec load_script: 'ansa123.py' -exec \"foo("+  ','.join(map(lambda x: "'" + str(x) +  "'", listofstrings)) +") \"")**

Comment: Of course, that's equivalent, just less clear IMO.

Comment: There's no prize for squeezing as much as you can onto one line.

Comment: Except I forgot to join with commas.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I should've tried to keep it simple. But yes, I tried to change it because there was a syntax error, and  it took me a while figuring it out.